# Launching on Android before iOS

Tags: android, ios, launching-application

*I did not know where else to turn for this question*

My present background is Android and Rails application development. I am building a social media type mobile app that allows for real-time messaging between users, and the creation/scheduling of events as well as a web component in rails.

In terms of launch, everywhere I look it notes not to launch to Android first, but focus on iOS, yet just about all of these sources are 2+ years old.

For the application that I have, generally described, is there any reason not to launch to Android first? Are the fears outlined in the articles outdated?

Comment: "I did not know where else to turn for this question" -- I would suggest a site related to sales and marketing. Or, perhaps any of [the other Android developer support sites](http://www.andglobe.com), where they may have less-stringent rules about what is and is not on-topic.

Comment: I think this is too opinion based for Stack Overflow, unfortunately. However, you might be able to get help on another Stack Exchange site, such as [Startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about sales and market research, not programming.

Comment: I'm curious what these sources are. Very curious who and why would say such a thing and for what reasons.

Comment: @SausageMachine They basically noted the issues of fragmentation given the number of different devices to design for as well as operating systems: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/appsblog/2013/aug/15/android-v-ios-apps-apple-google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a social network app for **Android** too and in my opinion you don't need to fear about selecting an OS for starting development. Start from where you are experienced. I'm good enough with Java and Android so I decided to start with Android. When I have a fully functional app than I will launch and start building the app for **iOS**. 
You should focus on the OS that you like and you are experienced with. I think these articles are oldies. But the decision is up to. 
You may want to read [this article](http://www.androidauthority.com/develop-apps-for-android-rather-than-ios-607219/)
Happy coding